# Justify legend text in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have the legend shown below:

[image]

On the left, the text is aligned, however, on the right the numbers are not aligned. How can I align the numbers too?

Comment: In the figure, double click on the legend, and edit it some how which you want.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I didn't know that. However, I prefer some code to fix this issue automatically. This is desired especially when I have to plot many figures.

Answer (score 3):

The tab command (\t) does not seem to work when providing strings to table entries. However, you can solve the problem if you work in the latex environment, define every entry as a single-row tabular and define the first column to have a specific width (e.g. 1 cm):

```
plot(eye(2)); % example plot
h=legend('\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}r}first:&1\end{tabular}',...
    '\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}r}second:&2\end{tabular}'); % table entries in latex
set(h,'interpreter','latex'); % set interpreter
```

[image]